# How to count number of word embeddings in Gensim Word2Vec model

Tags: word2vec, word-embeddings, gensim

I am trying to create a Word2Vec model of the the Pub Med Central corpus using the Gensim library and want to limit the total number of word embeddings to around 1 billion.

I have searched high and low and am unable to find out a) How to count the total number of word-embeddings in a saved model, and b) how to limit the total number of embeddings when training the model (once I hit 1 billion, then stop).

Please forgive my simpleton questions.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after digging around in methods available to my loaded Word2Vec model I believe the answer is `len(model.wv.vectors)`...